# Forge Viewer - Select Inventor part in a drawing

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

How can I select Inventor part in a drawing in Forge Viewer? Is it possible?
The drawing is a DWFx file generated from Inventor IDW.
I know that is possible in RVT file.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to select a part in inventor drawing in APS(former Forge) viewer because Model Derivative API doesn't translate the data into vieweable file.

Comment: It’s pity, maybe in future? Thanks for information.

Comment: The workaround I’m using for this issue is.

1． Change each drawing element’s layer by it’s occurrence name, while creating new layer which layer name is occurrence name.
2． Translate the drawing into AutoCAD dwg file.
3． Open the dwg file with AutoCAD and convert each layer entities into AutoCAD block.

Now, the AutoCAD dwg has blocks which block name is occurrence name in Inventor drawing, so you can select each occurrence in APS viewer.

Comment: You can automate this steps with Design Automation API.

I know this is complicated and not straight forward approach. And also there is some limitation on this workaround , e.g. you can select only 1 level blow occurrence in original drawing. So please check this workaround is available for your purpose, if you interested in it.

Comment: You can find sample source code for each steps in blow link, sorry the article is written in Japanese but at least you can know how to do it.
https://knowledge.autodesk.com/ja/support/inventor/learn-explore/caas/simplecontent/content/inventor-E3-81-AE2d-E5-9B-B3-E9-9D-A2-E3-81-AB-E9-85-8D-E7-BD-AE-E3-81-97-E3-81-9Fview-E5-86.html